# UIPickerView Wrap Around Swift 2

Tags: uipickerview, swift2, xcode7

I need help creating an UIPickerView to wrap around the options. So instead of the picker looking like this:

[image: right now]

I want it to look like this (without the "min"):

[image: what I want]

I looked everywhere, but I can't find a way to do it with Swift 2.0
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a very large number in

`func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int`

and select the middle row while initialzing with

`selectRow(COUNT/2, inComponent: 0, animated: true)`

See this [code sample](https://github.com/cybertk/CKPickerView/blob/bca13a4bb40a48d48ee14c2eec31f38e2f64459c/Example/ViewController.swift#L75-L89)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an explanation that makes for quicker use:

**Goal:**

Make your UIPickerView larger than the user will ever try to scroll

**Steps:**

(1) Extend your picker in size

```
func pickerView(numberOfRowsInComponent) -> Int {
    return 10_000;
}
```

(2) Access by Modulus

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return data[row%data.count];
}
```

(3) Init to Middle (after init)

```
picker.selectRow((10_000/2), inComponent: 0, animated: false);
```